# Anti-CSRF implementation in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, csrf, global-asax

I would like to implement Anti-CSRF token in Global.asax file of MVC 3. 
Is that possible to implement the same in Gloabl.asax file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems what you need is to create a custom filter class which implements `IAuthorizationFilter` for all `POST` methods, by checking `HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod` request:

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenEveryPost : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add the new filter in `FilterConfig` class:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenEveryPost());
    }
}
```

Also ensure that the custom filter has registered in `Global.asax` code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // other settings

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    // other settings
}
```

By using global filtering given above, all POST method requests are automatically checks for `AntiForgeryToken`, no matter if `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is not present inside view pages.

**Addendum 1:**

It is possible to exclude certain actions from CSRF token checking, what you need is preventing `Validate` method to execute while a custom attribute class is present. First, create a custom attribute class for validation check:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExcludeAntiForgeryCheckAttribute : Attribute
{
    // other stuff
}
```

Afterwards, use `ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes` to get custom attribute type created above:

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenEveryPost : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        // adapted from Darin Dimitrov (/a/34588606/)
        bool isValidate = !context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeAntiForgeryCheckAttribute), true).Any();

        // use AND operator (&&) if you want to exclude POST requests marked with custom attribute
        // otherwise, use OR operator (||)
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && isValidate)
        {
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can decorate any methods which should be exempted from CSRF validation token:

```
[HttpPost]
[ExcludeAntiForgeryCheck]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    // other stuff

    return View(model);
}
```

References:

[Check CRSF token by default in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/12/22/csrf-protection-by-default-in-asp-net-mvc/) (standard version)

[Securing all forms using AntiForgeryToken](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/securing_all_forms_using_antiforgerytoken) (attribute-based version)

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. I am new to MVC so I am not sure under which folder I need to create custom filter class. Could you plz suggest me on this?

Comment: I think your custom filtering class can be created inside `App_Start` directory or any directory you want, providing that project's root namespace used instead of `ProjectName.App_Start` or `ProjectName.FolderName`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. @Tetsuya Yamamoto

Comment: I would like to ignore CSRF check for home page alone. Because we are using SSO mechanism for our application. So it throws exception in homepage. Is there any possibility to resolve this.

Comment: @Ask_SO I updated additional information in "Addendum" section. Check if it's satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I think ExcludeAntiForgeryCheck attribute is not supported in MVC 3. Getting exception.

Comment: @Ask_SO What exception you get? In later MVC versions it worked, but not sure for earlier ones.

Comment: Getting Error in line 'bool isValidate = !context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeAntiForgeryCheck), true).Any();' Operator cannot be applied to operand of system.type

Comment: I mistakenly write `ExcludeAntiForgeryCheck`, `typeof(ExcludeAntiForgeryCheckAttribute)` is the proper one. Apologies for your inconvenience (edited the answer, retry if you wish to do).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. For each request we need to check token. 
Please try to use below code in view file.

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Comment: We can implement in each view page. But I want to implement the same in Global.asax file.